# select all objects with same attribute value as mouseover element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help setting the opacity to 1 for a whole column (or group of columns) on a mouseover event hovering over any object in the column in d3.

Here is the code:

```
        var svg = d3.select("#right-section").append("svg").attr("width",600).attr("height",600);
        var flatInputMatrix = [1,1,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,2,0,4,4,0,0,0,5,5,0,1,0,2,2];
        var m = 5;
        var r = 3;

        var counter = -1;

        var data = flatInputMatrix.map(function(d, i) {
          i % m === 0 ? counter++ : null;
          return {
            column: i % m,
            row: counter,
            value: d
          };
        });

        var numbers = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(data).enter().append("text")
            .attr("x",function(d,i) { return (i % m)*50 + 10 + r; })
            .attr("y",function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i / m) *50+50; })
            .style("opacity", 0.5)
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
            .on("mouseover",function(d) {return d.column.transition().style("opacity", 1); })
```

I know this last line is wrong, I get

```
TypeError: d.column.transition is not a function
```

but I'm not sure how to approach fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `d3.select(this)`to get the context of whatever you're mousing over.

```
 .style("opacity", "0.5")
 .on("mouseover", function(d){d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1")  });
```

```js
        //based on candlestick6panzoooom.html
       
          var candleWidth = 20;
          var candleGap = 40;
          var candleMargin = 10;
          var wickThickness = "2";
          var hLineColor = "#b5b6b7";
    
          var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60},
          width = 940 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 640 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var rand = [];

    var data = [{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 13.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 12.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 13.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 12.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 13.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 12.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 13.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 12.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 3.99,
                Low: 0.007,
                Open: 0.75,
                Close: 2.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 4.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 2.514,
                Close: 2.88
   },{
                Date: 01 / 12 / 15,
                High: 2.99,
                Low: 0.0007,
                Open: 1.75,
                Close: 1.04
            }, {
                Date: 02 / 12 / 15,
                High: 5.976,
                Low: 0.001,
                Open: 1.514,
                Close: 3.88
   }
 ];

    var maxi = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    }); 

    var maxLow = d3.min(data.map(function(x) {
        return x["Low"];
      }))
    var maxHigh = d3.max(data.map(function(x) {
        return x["High"];
      })) 
    var maxMinDiff = (maxHigh - maxLow) * 0.1;

    function min(a, b) {
      return a < b ? a : b;
    };

    function max(a, b) {
      return a > b ? a : b;
    };

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-width);

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([-width / 2, width / 2]).range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([maxLow - maxMinDiff, maxHigh + maxMinDiff]) //changed to reflect new variables for lowest, highest and difference to define input domain
      .range([height, 0]); //range has still not been modified ... remember x,y have been reversed to reflect y,x


    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 32])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);
      
    var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
    var grid = chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "gridding");

    var lines = grid.selectAll("line.y")
      .data(y.ticks(20))
      .enter()
      .append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "y")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y1", y)
      .attr("y2", y)
      .attr("stroke", hLineColor);

    var numbers = grid.selectAll("text.yrule")
      .data(y.ticks(10))
      .enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "yrule")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("dy", 0)
      .attr("dx", 20)
      .style("fill", "#b5b6b7")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

//    chart.append("clipPath")
//      .attr("id", "clip")
//      .append("rect")
//      .attr("width", width)
//      .attr("height", height);
//      
//    chart.append("rect")
//      .attr("class", "pane")
//      .attr("width", width)
//      .attr("height", height)
//      .call(zoom)
//      .style("fill","none")
//      .style("pointer-events", "all");

    var candlestick = chart.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "candlesticks")

  
    function buildChart(data) {
      
     
      var wicks = candlestick.selectAll("wick")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + candleWidth / 2 + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return y(max(d.High, d.Low));
        }) 
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return y(min(d.High, d.Low));
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {
          return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", wickThickness);

    
      var candle = candlestick.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return candleMargin + (candleGap * i);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return y(min(d.Open, d.Close)) - y(max(d.Open, d.Close));
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return candleWidth
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return d.Open > d.Close ? "#a01f1b" : "#1ba048";
        })
        .style("opacity", "0.5")
  .on("mouseover", function(d){d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1")  });

    } 
    buildChart(data);

  var movingAvg = function (data, neighbors)
      {
     console.log("neighbours is: "+neighbors)
      return data.map( function(val, idx, arr)
    {
        let start = Math.max(0, idx - neighbors)
     let end = idx + neighbors
        let subset = arr.slice(start, end + 1)
        let sum = subset.reduce((a,b) => a + b)
    console.log(sum)
        return sum / subset.length
      })
     } 
  
     var band = []
//     for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
//      {
//       band.push(250*(Math.random()))
//      }
//     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
//     {
//    band.push(data[i].Close)
//    console.log(band[i])
//     }
    var dataAvg = movingAvg(band, 0) 

    var avgX = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])
    //.range([0, width])
    .range([0, (candleMargin + (candleGap * data.length))])
    
    var avgY = d3.scale
     .linear()
     .domain([0, height])
     .rangeRound([height/2,height])

    var avg = candlestick.append("g").attr("class", "average")

    var curvedLine = 
     
     d3.svg.line()
     .x((d,i) => avgX(i))
     .y(d => avgY(d))
     .interpolate("basis")
      
      avg.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'avg')
      .datum(dataAvg)
      .attr('d', curvedLine)
          .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)

   
  
  
  
  

    function zoomed() {
      candlestick.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ")")
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used d3.select(this) now, but it only changes the opacity on the one element I am hovering over. I would like to do something like this:

.on("mouseover", function(d.column){d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1)  })

which doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you using groups for that??

Comment: thank you, just asked another question about grouping here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443265/group-by-object-attributes-in-array#

Comment: You can't add transitions to groups I don't think, you may want to look into writing a function that'll loop through your set setting the opacity to 1, depending how large your dataset is it'll seem instantaneous hopefully!

Comment: @JamieHyland You **can** add transitions to groups.